# filter.Words not working while calling noteStore.findNotesMetadata() in c#

Tags: c#-4.0

I'm trying to filter notes by using search word e.g.

```
NoteFilter filter = new NoteFilter();
filter.Words = "dummy";
NotesMetadataResultSpec spec = new NotesMetadataResultSpec();
spec.IncludeTitle = true;
NotesMetadataList notesList = noteStore.findNotesMetadata(api.AccessToken, filter, 0, pageSize, spec);
```

But not working.

It's not giving any error message but I'm expecting notes should be filter by NoteFilter.words field passed down to findNotesMetadata.

Comment: I'm using source code from below repository

https://github.com/evernote/evernote-sdk-csharp/tree/master/src
https://github.com/apache/thrift

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? No matter what I put under "words" it never works.